# Twitter4j connection error 403

Tags: twitter4j

I am trying to collect "usertimeline" data from Twitter search Api using Twitter4j. It was properly working  before but now it's saying a 403 error has occurred. I didn't change my source code.

My source code like below.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("*************")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("*************")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("*************")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*************");
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter2 = tf.getInstance();


ResponseList<Status> statuses;   
Paging page2 = new Paging(); 
page2.count(4); 
page2.setPage(1);   
String pro ="";

try {   
    statuses = twitter2.getUserTimeline(page2);

    for (Status status : statuses) {    
        pro = pro + status.getText() 

        out.print(pro+"//");
    }           
}  
catch(TwitterException te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
    out.print(te.toString());
}
```

If anybody knows about my source code problem, please help me out.

Comment: Check if your keys are still active in the twitter api.

Comment: i used my keys in my twitter account. is it have another way?

Answer (score 0):

Recently i got the same error while executing similar code.
To fix it, please go to

1. https://apps.twitter.com/app/your_app_id
2. Click on Keys and access token
3. In Access Level, click modify app permission and choose the 3rd option: Read, Write and Access direct messages
4. Click on update. ( Note: you might have to add your mobile no and verify with otp to get this access if you dont have your no added in twitter)
5. Regenerate both Consumer key & secretand Access token & secret using the clickable button

And you are done! Your program will start working.